# C51 Compiler - Write to xdata

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, 8051

Programming on a XC888 microcontroller, I want to save a buffer for some data in the external memory `xdata`.

I am doing it like this (just an example, where I got rid of unnecessary code):

Header.h

```
extern ubyte xdata rec_buffer[32];
```

Function.c

```
ubyte xdata rec_buffer[32] = {0};

void foo()
{
    //Option 1
    rec_buffer[0] = 0xFF;    // Doesn't work

    //Option 2
    ubyte xdata *ptr_buf = rec_buffer;
    ptr_buf[0] = 0xFF        // Doesn't work
}
```

So I just can't figure out what I am missing here. In both cases, there is no data written into the buffer. (Checked it with the debugger). I also checked the address where the pointers point it --> It actually points in the External memory (Address `0x000000`, but there should be nothing wrong with that).

When I do it without defining the buffer in the `xdata` it works totally fine. 
What am I doing wrong? Is there some special way I have to write into the xdata?

Comment: Do you tried to set it via the debugger, and read it back? Perhaps the debugger doesn't show the real values

Comment: Well I tried reading it back into a normal uchar variable and then looking if it got the desired value. But it also gets 0, so I guess the debugger shows me the right values.

Comment: From where are you trying to access the buffer? From the main program or an interrupt service routine, or both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't XRAM be at `0xF000` (not `0x000000`)?  According to Figure 7 here:

http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/infineon/xc88xclm_ds.pdf

Is the linker configuration wrong somewhere?

Comment: Yes, checked that out - you're completely right - when I reconfigure the linker that xdata lies at 0xF000 it works totally fine. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Use volatile keyword for your buffer, most probably variable is skipped by compiler. If you write a value to a memory or I/O space but not observe the value or any change, most probably your variable is optimized by compiler.

Comment: Well I just tried it and this doesn't help. But I don't see how this should help either. I mean even if the compiler takes some optimizations, it still is there. I mean I have the pointer and I have the buffer and through Debugging I can also see the memory of the variables and the pointer pointing there. Also the compiler doesn't give me any warning or error about the variable not being accessable